# Entity Framework Core 8 dbcontext - can't add some rows in many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Can someone explain me why I get this error

> INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ArticleTag_Tags_ArticleId". The conflict occurred in database "Blog", table "dbo.Tags", column 'TagId'"

```
public class Article
{
    public Article()
    {
        Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string ArticleName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? ArticleDescription { get; set; }
    public bool Visibility { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    [InverseProperty("Articles")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Article")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TagId")]         
    [InverseProperty("Articles")] 
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public Tag() 
    { 
        Articles = new HashSet<Article>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ArticleId")]
    [InverseProperty("Tags")]
    public virtual ICollection<Article>? Articles { get; set; }
}
```

After migration, with 50 articles and 20 tags, I cannot add a new row to (autogenerated) `ArticleTag` table where `ArticleId` is greater than 20.

I have no idea what this is about, can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreign keys of the join table are linked incorrectly - `TagId` to `Articles.ArticleId` and `ArticleId` to `Tags.TagId`. It can also be seen in the error message or the generated migration. And of course in the model in case you look carefully - one reason I don't like `ForeignKey` attribute is its multipurpose and different meanings depending on where you apply it, thus very error prone.

You need to correct the model and generate/apply new migration:

```cs
public class Article
{    
    [ForeignKey("ArticleId")] // <-- was [ForeignKey("TagId")]
    [InverseProperty("Articles")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [ForeignKey("TagId")] // <-- was [ForeignKey("ArticleId")]
    [InverseProperty("Tags")]
    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```